# I want to make a this count object but i dont know how to solve it

Tags: javascript, object, count

```js
function test1(str) {
  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  let obj = {};
  let len = arr.length;
     
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (obj[arr[i]]) {
      obj[arr[i]] ++
    } else if(obj[arr[i]] === " ") {
      obj[arr[i]] = 0;
    } else {
      obj[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
  }
      return obj;
}

let output = obectCount('ask a bunch try a BUNCH get a bunch');
console.log(output); // --> { ask: 1, a: 3, bunch: 3, try: 1, get: 1 };
```

I expect it to be `{ ask: 1, a: 3, bunch: 3, try: 1, get: 1 };` but it is wrong in various cases - how can I fix it?

Thank you for your interest. But there was a problem with the other conditions.
its  other condition , just updated..

```js
let output1 = test1('  a  b c d C b A ')
console.log(output);  // --> { a: 2, b: 2, c: 2, d: 1 }
let output2 = test1(" ")
console.log(output); // --> {}
```

Comment: First thing to spot is the typo `obectCount`.

Comment: thanks! but i have a other condition, its still happend error..ㅠ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the idea basically is check if the object exist

- If yes increment the counter
- If no create a property and initialize its counter with 1

```js
function objectCount(str) {
  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  let obj = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, arr[i])){
      obj[arr[i]]++;
    } else {
      obj[arr[i]] = 1;

    }
  }
  return obj;
}


let output = objectCount('ask a bunch try a BUNCH get a bunch');
console.log(output); // --> { ask: 1, a: 3, bunch: 3, try: 1, get: 1 };
```

Comment: This seems like the best way! I like the simplicity. Although I would suggest using `hasOwnProperty` instead of implictly comparing to undefined, since that's guaranteed to always be correct: `if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, arr[i])) {` Also, you're initializing a `count` variable that you're not using.

Comment: but how can i distinguish blank ?  i mean..,i have a more condition, 
```js
let output1 = test1('  a  b c d C b A ')
console.log(output);  // --> { a: 2, b: 2, c: 2, d: 1 }
let output2 = test1(" ")
console.log(output); // --> {}
```

Comment: you can do a check if your string contains at least one character at the beginning of your objectCount Method `if(str.trim().length > 0){ do the stuff}else{your string is empty }` the trim method to remove whitespaces. Shall I update it to my answer? @Loolii

Comment: Thank you so much. but.. the method is forbbiden.. omg..x.x. i also search this method but cant using..

Comment: @Loolii forbidden, can you do a fiddle with it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've already stopped the problem from company. Still, it was very helpful. Thank you very much for your effort. I'll have to study a little more.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution.

```js
function objectCount(str) {
  let obj = {};
  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  arr.forEach(item=>{obj[item] = (obj[item] || 0) + 1});
  return obj;
}


let output = objectCount('ask a bunch try a BUNCH get a bunch');
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `includes` set the count of a specific word to 1 if appears for the first time, if appears for the second time simply increment that value. If you use `arr.inclueds()`, it will just check whether a specific word exists in that array or not, you can't check whether it appears for the first time or not. Here is the working example:

```js
function objectCount(str) {
    let arr = str.split(" ");
    let obj = {};
    let len = arr.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (obj[arr[i]]) {
            obj[arr[i]] += 1;
        } else {
            obj[arr[i]] = 1;
        }
    }

    return obj;
}

let output = objectCount('ask a bunch try a BUNCH get a bunch'.toLowerCase());
console.log(output); // --> { ask: 1, a: 3, bunch: 3, try: 1, get: 1 };
```

Comment: It s wrong you have to lowercase it, expected is bunch = 3

Comment: @Loolii, my pleasure.

Comment: i m realised includes is not good method in this problem.. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using reduce method:

```js
function objectCount(str) {
 return str.split(" ").reduce((output,word)=> {
   const wc= (output[word.toLowerCase()] || 0) + 1
  
   return ({...output,[word.toLowerCase()]:wc}
          )},{})
 
} 

let output = objectCount('ask a bunch try a BUNCH get a bunch');
console.log(output); // --> { ask: 1, a: 3, bunch: 3, try: 1, get: 1 };
```